# grub "unknown filesystem" error on boot

Tags: grub2

When booting via grub I get the following error:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos7) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0)
grub resuce> set
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5
```

If I change the root and prefix to hd0,msdos6 I can boot successfully. Except grub encounters the same error when I reboot. How can I get grub to remember these settings?

Potentially useful information:

- I am using RAID0 and grub is installed to /dev/mapper/isw_fbifcgeic_RaidVolume0
- In Linux (Ubuntu 11.10) my grub.cfg points to root at (hd2,msdos6)
- `grub-mkdevicemap -m -` lists the /dev/mapper entry at hd2

Any help would be much appreciated! It's super annoying needing to rescue grub every time I boot my system.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my raid0 configuration was really a "fakeraid" configuration. It also turns out that there was a [bug in grub-probe](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/803658) related to fakeraid. Once I ran `sudo update grub-pc` followed by `grub-install /dev/mapper/isw_fbifcgeic_RaidVolume0` I could successfully boot my computer once more without manual intervention.